# Print hibernate sql query with parameters into logs

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, log4j2, hibernate-5.x

I am able to print SQL query and binded params but not the limit values.
I am using hibernate 5.2 and spring boot 2.2.3 and log4j2 for logging.

I am able to print in a different log file by enabling below 2 properties

**`org.hibernate.SQL, org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql`**

but unable to print the

**`select * from (select id, desc from table where pId = ?) where rownum >= ?`**

I can print the first question mark (binded value) but not the second question mark value

Any help appreciated.